# If the kernel is Linux, the desktop, and DM is Gnome, then what exactly is Ubuntu?

Tags: terminology

If the kernel is Linux, the desktop, and DE is Gnome (or Unity or KDE or whatever), then what exactly are Ubuntu, Debian and other linux OS'es?

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu, Debian, antiX, Mint, Kali, etc. are "distributions," sometimes called "distros".  This convention has existed for *at least* fifteen years.

There's even a website devoted to the various distributions called [distrowatch.com](https://distrowatch.com/).